# MakeFile not executing by mingw32-make

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, mingw, mingw32

I am trying to run code of a GitHub repository. Link --> https://github.com/ViDA-NYU/urban-pulse#windows-7-8-10
This first build executes a MakeFile through a mingw32-make command on cmd.exe. That execution is showing a "syntax error: unexpected end of file" error.
[image: Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CJErtpVviLCileL0xPNaHyBnkVoqJBWf).
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CJErtpVviLCileL0xPNaHyBnkVoqJBWf

I tried to execute it with MinGW mingw32-make and MSYS make but none worked. I have installed MinGW from the official website.

Here is the MakeFile up to line 43. The name of the file is "MakeFile"

```
#############################################################################
# Makefile for building: ComputePulse
# Generated by qmake (3.0) (Qt 5.6.2)
# Project:  ComputePulse.pro
# Template: subdirs
# Command: C:\Users\Kanishk\Anaconda3\Library\bin\qmake.exe -o Makefile ComputePulse.pro
#############################################################################

MAKEFILE      = Makefile

first: make_first
QMAKE         = C:\Users\Kanishk\Anaconda3\Library\bin\qmake.exe
DEL_FILE      = del
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= if not exist
MKDIR         = mkdir
COPY          = copy /y
COPY_FILE     = copy /y
COPY_DIR      = xcopy /s /q /y /i
INSTALL_FILE  = copy /y
INSTALL_PROGRAM = copy /y
INSTALL_DIR   = xcopy /s /q /y /i
DEL_FILE      = del
SYMLINK       = $(QMAKE) -install ln -f -s
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = move
SUBTARGETS    =  \
        sub-Scalars-Scalars-pro \
        sub-PulseJNI-Pulse-pro


sub-Scalars-Scalars-pro-qmake_all:  FORCE
    @if not exist Scalars\ mkdir Scalars\ & if not exist Scalars\ exit 1
    cd Scalars\ && $(QMAKE) E:\BTP\urban-pulse-master\ComputePulse\Scalars\Scalars.pro -o Makefile
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd Scalars\ && $(MAKE) -f Makefile qmake_all
sub-Scalars-Scalars-pro: FORCE
    @if not exist Scalars\ mkdir Scalars\ & if not exist Scalars\ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd Scalars\ && ( if not exist Makefile $(QMAKE) E:\BTP\urban-pulse-master\ComputePulse\Scalars\Scalars.pro -o Makefile ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile
sub-Scalars-Scalars-pro-make_first: FORCE
    @if not exist Scalars\ mkdir Scalars\ & if not exist Scalars\ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd Scalars\ && ( if not exist Makefile $(QMAKE) E:\BTP\urban-pulse-master\ComputePulse\Scalars\Scalars.pro -o Makefile ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile
```

The execution is expected to create two executables named Scalars and Pulse. Information is also available on the link above.

Comment: From the page: "Download Qt 5.8 (or later version)" - you have 5.6.2. This cannot work! You must update your Qt installation to at least 5.8 (But I would recommend to use 5.12 - the latest LTS-release)

Comment: Thanks for your time sir, Actually I downloaded it 3 days ago using the Qt installer and I have downloaded the latest version available i.e. 5.13.0. I know that the code I have posted shows Qt 5.6.2 on the commented line no. 3. Maybe that line was added on for the previous version and was never edited, as it a comment... Update: I have checked in my PC all the files are named as 5.13.0...

Comment: 5.13 was not released yet, its still in Alpha state! Use 5.12.1 instead. Make shure you use the qmake that is part of your Qt installation. As seen in there to, it uses the qmake located at `C:\Users\Kanishk\Anaconda3\Library\bin\qmake.exe` - which is propably the wrong one! Do so by calling it explicitly, i.e. `C:\Qt\5.12.1\mingw73_64\bin\qmake.exe`

Comment: If you paste `if not exist Scalars\ mkdir Scalars\ & if not exist Scalars\ exit 1` into your msys window does it work? (i.e. does it create a directory called Scalars? A problem appears to be that you are running windows commands on a linux-like interface.  `/usr/bin/sh` is a linux-like shell. It would not expect or work with windows commands. The makefile is full of windows shell commands - I mean have you tried running it bog-standard DOS/cmd.exe?

Comment: @Felix Sir, Now I have tried it with version 5.12.1 and 5.9 both, as well but it still does not run.

Comment: I can't reproduce with *qmake 3.1*, *QT 5.12.0* and *MinGW 7.3.0*.